Ubuntu 24.04 : error "failed to write entry to /var/log/journal" after screen lock
I've upgrated from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04.1, and everything was OK.
Recently I've replaced the 8GB RAM with 2x16GB RAM, and then the problems began:
If screen is locked for a while, I can't login again. I have the user icon without image, and I'm unable to enter my password. When I launch another terminal session, I have errors :
systemd-journal [xxx]: Failed to write entry to /var/log/journal

This is the screen capture of the errors :

Then I have to reboot each time screen is locked! The problem remains with both NVIDIA and intel graphic device.
It seems like a write permission issue, but I don't know how to handle this!
